# Combo box with processes that works for memory.dll c#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, process

I know there's a similaar question about this, but read it first

I'm using Windows 10 x64

I'm writing something in c# with memory.dll so I want to show the processes and then write a value with memory.dll in the process the user selects.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Mem m = new Mem();
        
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadprocess();
        }


private void loadprocess()
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            Process[] MyProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
            for (int i = 0; i < MyProcess.Length; i++)
                comboBox1.Items.Add(MyProcess[i].ProcessName + "-" + MyProcess[i].Id);
        }

private void timerDontCamera_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m.OpenProcess(Process.GetProcessesByName(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().Id);
            m.WriteMemory("zVideoUI.dll+003BED80,68,E4", "byte", "1");
        }
```

The problem is this line:

```
m.OpenProcess(Process.GetProcessesByName(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()).FirstOrDefault().Id);
           m.WriteMemory("zVideoUI.dll+003BED80,68,E4", "byte", "1");
```

It throws an exception: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SelectedValue.get returned null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, I reproduced your problem.

First, I recommend that you use `comboBox1.SelectedItem` to replace `comboBox1.SelectedValue`.

Second, we should get the process name if we want to use `Process.GetProcessesByName` method. However, your `comboBox` selected Items should be `processname` + `process.id`.

Finally, you can try the following code to get the correct Id.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadprocess();
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
        }


        private void loadprocess()
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            Process[] MyProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
            for (int i = 0; i < MyProcess.Length; i++)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(MyProcess[i].ProcessName + "-" + MyProcess[i].Id);
            }
        
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string processname = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('-').First();
        string id = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('-').Last();
        var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processname).Where(i=>i.Id==Convert.ToInt32(id)).First();
        Console.WriteLine(process.Id);
        m.OpenProcess(process.Id);
        }
```

Make a test for it:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what to do because I know there are 3 processes with the same name, in cheat engine I choose the one is correct and it shows me the value, but with this c# it says that the value can't be found, that means it is taking one of the other 2 processes with the same name

Comment: @José Antonio, it seems that you want to find the correspond process based on the combobox. I have updated my code, you can have a try.

Comment: I've checked and I'm almost sure that the combobox doesn't show proceesses with the same name, because I've been searching and I can't find the other process while Cheat Engine does it without any problem. If I try the process that appears there it says that my pointer can't be found

Comment: Investigating a little more, I've found that the two processes are there but it says it didn't found my pointer while cheat engine does it just nice

Comment: My fault, my project had to be x86, I tried without your code and it doesn't work, so your response was helpful, thanks.